# Can't restore document from version history on Sanity

Tags: sanity

I can't restore previous document version from the version history on Sanity without notifying anything.

I can remember I could restore the previous document version in the last month.
It was showing me a notification with this sentence: `Successfully performed restore on document.`

But, not I can't see any notification or any error messages.

How can I check what has been wrong?

Is there a way to check the sanity activity logs?

I choose the version from the version history on Sanity document.
And clicked on Restore button. And then click on the confirm button.
I expected to the document restored, but it shows me the latest document without any error messages.
That is, nothing happened.